# How can I remove elements with a class when its header matches the page title?

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pageTitle = $('h3.title-hidden');
    if (title === pageTitle) {
        $('.content-hidden').remove();
    }
});
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where do you define `title`?

Comment: @JoeClay: It's a global on web pages. It's the title of the page.

Comment: it's working with pug

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) This question is missing a **lot** of necessary detail. For instance, add the HTML, explain how `h3.title-hidden` and `.content-hidden` relate to each other, etc.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers. *(I fixed it for you.)*

Answer (score 1):

`pageTitle` is the jQuery object that wraps the `h3` element. It doesn't contain the *text* of that element. If you want the text, use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
var pageTitle = $('h3.title-hidden').text();
```

That assumes, based on your code, that there's just one `h3.title-hidden` on the page, and that you want to remove all `.content-hidden` elements if that one element's text matches the document title.